# bash: service: command not found

Tags: macos, bash, mac, .bash-profile

I was having an issue running a `mysql` command and saw suggestions on a few issues online that suggested using the `service` command and it seemed to be that it was something that I should have by default.

I had been installing a few homebrew packages, so I'm not sure if that could have caused it? I have never used this command before, so I'm not entirely sure.

Attempting to run the command `sudo service mysql start`
returns

```
sudo: service: command not found
```

I have not got much experience using the terminal, so apologies. I saw a lot of comments suggesting that the service command is located in `/usr/sbin/` and also possibly `/sbin/service` but I could not find it in either.

my .bash_profile is as follows

```
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/sbin
```

The two exports at the bottom were from suggestions in other questions but neither seemed to work.

Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use something like `ls /{{s,}bin,usr/{s,}bin}/service` to see where `service` is located - but I fear macos uses a different way to handle services. See e.g. https://serverfault.com/q/194832/453007

Comment: @choroba Thanks for the replay, `service` does not appear in any of the folder, running that command returns ```ls: /bin/service: No such file or directory
ls: /sbin/service: No such file or directory
ls: /usr/bin/service: No such file or directory
ls: /usr/sbin/service: No such file or directory```

Comment: On a recent system mysql is perhaps handled by `systemd` (on some systems init.d has been totally replaced by `systemd`, on older systems they still coexist). See if `systemctl status mysql*` seems to know about `mysql`, if so `mysql`is a `systemd` service and can be controlled with the `systemctl` command.

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @davidgo None of them. The mention of Homebrew makes it clear that the OP is using macOS.

Answer (score 11):

The `service` command is specific to certain Linux distributions. It is not used on macOS.

If you installed MySQL through Homebrew, you can start and stop it using the commands:

```
brew services start mysql
brew services stop mysql
```